# Does the subscription has unlimited lifetime?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, subscription, microsoft-graph-sdks

I wonder does the subscriptions (Microsoft Graph API) have a limited or unlimited lifetime? Is there any related documentation or guidance available for this... I failed to find one.

Comment: Yes, Subscriptions for Microsoft Graph have a limited lifetime. For a list of maximum expiration times, see Maximum length of subscription per resource type documentation - (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#subscription-lifetime).

Comment: Thanks @Dev. It answers my question!!

Comment: Have a side question. What about apps/clients?

Comment: Apps need to renew their subscriptions before the expiration time. Otherwise, they need to create a new subscription. Apps can also unsubscribe at any time to stop getting change notifications. Clients can create subscriptions, renew subscriptions, and delete subscriptions.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help @Dev!! You rock!!

Comment: Glad to hear the above helped!!

Comment: I will move this to answer. Please upvote, so it can be useful to others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, Subscriptions in Microsoft Graph have a limited lifetime.
- For a list of maximum expiration times, see Maximum length of
  subscription per resource type [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#subscription-lifetime).
- Apps need to renew their subscriptions before the expiration time. Otherwise, they need to create a new subscription. Apps can also unsubscribe at any time to stop getting change notifications. Clients can create subscriptions, renew subscriptions, and delete subscriptions.